# How do I select the same features in my test data that I selected in my train data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, kaggle

I'm working through the house prices competition on kaggle. I have a data preparation function that does feature selection using Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) like this:

```
rfe = RFE(estimator=ElasticNet(), n_features_to_select=10)
X_selected = rfe.fit_transform(X, y)
X = pd.DataFrame(X_selected)
```

Where `X, y = dataset.iloc[:,:-1], dataset.iloc[:,-1:]` This works fine when I use the training dataset but it doesn't when I use the test dataset as it has no `y` variable.

My question is, how can I select the same features I did when using the training dataset?

I have the same problem with dimensionality reduction using `TruncatedSVD`:

```
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=30)
X_trans = svd.fit_transform(X)
X = pd.DataFrame(X_trans)
```

Where I have the set X (train) and a set datasetTest (test) and I want the same features to be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, your problem is that you cannot do `fit_transform` on the test set since you do not have a y variable.

You could access the rfe.support_ which returns which features were selected.

```
rfe = RFE(estimator=ElasticNet(), n_features_to_select=10)
X_selected = rfe.fit_transform(X, y)
X = pd.DataFrame(X_selected)

X_test_selected = X_test[:, rfe.support_]  # Picking the selected features
```

The `rfe.support` contains a mask of `[True False... True]` where `True` means that the feature was selected.

You can read more in [scikit documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFE).

Comment: Is there anything like ```support_``` for dimensionality reduction using TruncatedSVD as this step happens before feature selection but with a similar problem?

Comment: Yep, just do a `transform`. Look Arne's answer for code.

Comment: Although correct, this answer is kind of a hack; the canonical way is to just do `rfe.transform()`, as the other answer suggests (which also works in other cases, such as dimensionality reduction).

Answer (score 3):

[`RFE`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) has a `transform` method, so you can do something like this (after fitting the selector to your training data):

```py
X_test_selected = rfe.transform(X_test)
```